# How to use nested NamedDomainObjectContainer in Java

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have been trying to create a custom plugin with an extension that has has nested `NamedDomainObjectContainer`'s. I keep getting a strange error if I implement it in Java using `Action` compared to the same thing in Groovy using `Closure`.

Here is the Groovy one:

```
package com.example.gradle

import org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.Plugin

class DeploymentPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    void apply(final Project project) {
        def servers = project.container(Server)
        servers.all {
            nodes = project.container(Node)
        }
        project.extensions.add('deployments', servers)
    }

    static class Server {
        NamedDomainObjectContainer<Node> nodes
        String url
        String name

        Server(String name) {
            this.name = name
        }

        def nodes(final Closure configureClosure) {
            nodes.configure(configureClosure)
        }
    }

    static class Node {
        String name
        Integer port

        Node(String name) {
            this.name = name
        }
    }
}
```

And the Java one:

```
package com.example.gradle;

import org.gradle.api.Action;
import org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer;
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;

public class DeploymentPlugin2 implements Plugin<Project> {

    public void apply(final Project project) {
        final NamedDomainObjectContainer<Server2> servers = project.container(Server2.class);
        servers.all(it ->
                it.nodes = project.container(Node2.class)
        );
        project.getExtensions().add("deployments2", servers);
    }

    public static class Server2 {
        public NamedDomainObjectContainer<Node2> nodes;
        public String url;
        public String name;

        public Server2(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void nodes(final Action<? super NamedDomainObjectContainer<Node2>> action) {
            action.execute(nodes);
        }
    }

    public static class Node2 {
        public String name;
        public Integer port;

        public Node2(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

And the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: com.example.gradle.DeploymentPlugin
apply plugin: com.example.gradle.DeploymentPlugin2

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.4.1'
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}

deployments {
    aws {
        url = 'http://aws.address'

        nodes {
            node1 {
                port = 9000
            }
            node2 {
                port = 80
            }
        }
    }

    cf {
        url = 'http://cf.address'

        nodes {
            test {
                port = 10001
            }
            acceptanceTest {
                port = 10002
            }
        }
    }
}

deployments2 {
    aws {
        url = 'http://aws.address'

        nodes {
            node1 {
                port = 9000
            }
            node2 {
                port = 80
            }
        }
    }

    cf2 {
        url = 'http://cf.address'

        nodes {
            test {
                port = 10001
            }
            acceptanceTest {
                port = 10002
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which fails with:

```
PS C:\source\gradle-nested-doc-bug> ./gradlew tasks

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\source\gradle-nested-doc-bug\build.gradle' line: 42

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle-nested-doc-bug'.
> Could not find method node1() for arguments [build_afudfj5pxfy9w4tkoowa6djon$_run_closure3$_closure12$_closure14$_closure15@4724dfaa] on object of type com.example.gradle.DeploymentPlugin2$Server2.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

There is something funky going on with nested `NamedDomainObjectContainer`'s when using `Action`.

Any idea what is wrong with this?

Comment: Have you managed to solve it? Stick with the same with gradle 7.3

Answer (score -1):

Something Like:

```
import org.gradle.api.Project;

public static class Server2 {

    Project project;
    public NamedDomainObjectContainer<Node2> nodes = getProject().container(Node2.class);
    public String url;
    public String name;

    public Server2(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void nodes(final Action<? super NamedDomainObjectContainer<Node2>> action) {
        action.execute(nodes);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just reposting what I put in my original question and does not at all answer the nested `NamedDomainObjectContainer` problem.

Comment: Apologies - something went wrong when I did this - basically if you give your class access to the project you can see the containers. I note in 5.5.5 RC there is new support in the objectFactiory for these, https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/af75633255f00278157f880942196c169f82cf1c/subprojects/do